# How to generate a large number of $3\times 1$ random matrices?

Tags: random

I want to generate $1,000,000$ $3\times 1$ matrices, where the range of random number in each element of the matrix is different.

```
n = 1000000;
ParallelTable[{RandomReal[{(-4 π)/(3 Sqrt[3]), (4 π)/(
  3 Sqrt[3])}], RandomReal[{(-2 π)/(3), (2 π)/(3)}],
 RandomReal[{-π, π}]}, n]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Can someone suggest a much faster/elegant way, if any, to generate this? Also, if you think this will not work, can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
Transpose[
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 10^6}] N@{4 π/(3 Sqrt[3]), 2 π/3, π}
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.032924, Null}